# How to provide unique element IDs for items generated by a Repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using `Repeater` in ASP.Net. I am accessing content from the data base. Every id or class of html element is same. It is a new heading in multiple. There is read button.

I want to open a new page with full description of that heading in a new page.
I have problem in assigning unique id from which I know which heading is clicked.

This is the code of that part:

```
<div class="content">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="contl">
                    <div>
                        <asp:Repeater ID="RepCountry" runat="server"    OnItemCommand="RepCountry_ItemCommand">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <div class="contentbox">
                                    <div class="postheading">
                                        <%#Eval("title")%>
                                    </div>

                                    <table>
                                    <tr><td> <div class="postimage">
                                        <img src="Admin/images/<%# Eval("img")%>" alt="" height="50%" width="100%" />
                                    </div></td>
                                    <td><div class="discp">
                                        <div class="dpost">
                                            <p style="font-family: Times New Roman">
                                                <%#Eval("p_date")%></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="discp_c">
                                            <p>
                                                <%# Eval("descr").ToString().Substring(0,200).ToString()%></p>
                                            <p style="color: Maroon">
                                                <a id="A1"+ href="Readmore.aspx?oid=" runat="server" onclick="changeid(this.id)">Read More.</a></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="social">
                                            <a href="">
                                                <img src="images/t.png" alt="twtter" /></a> <a href="">
                                                    <img src="images/f.png" alt="facebook" /></a> <a href="">
                                                        <img src="images/g.png" alt="gmail" /></a> <a href="">
                                                            <img src="images/in.png" alt="linkedin" /></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div></td></tr>
                                    </table>


                                </div>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you have already used Eval to insert a Description in your items:

```
<div class="discp_c">
    <p>
        <%# Eval("descr").ToString().Substring(0,200).ToString()%></p>
    <p style="color: Maroon">
...
```

If I read the code well, you are reading at least `title, descr, img` the database query?

If so, then make sure that the query also returns the ID (Primary Key) of the article, and use `Eval` to insert that ID in the link. So, if the primary key of the article in the database is named for example `articleID`, then change your database query from

```
SELECT xxx as title, yyy as descr, zzz as img ....
```

to

```
SELECT id as articleID, xxx as title, yyy as descr, zzz as img ....
```

Then you can use the ID provided by the database to make a full link to an article:

```
<a runat='server' ....
   href='Readmore.aspx?oid=<%# Eval("articleID").ToString()%>'
   ....>
   ...</a>
```

and so the `Readmore.aspx` page will exactly know which article should be opened. It will come directly as `oid` query parameter, no extra work to do.

If you really need it, you can use the same trick to generate the HTML ID of that tag:

```
<a runat='server' ....
   id='ID_<%# Eval("articleID").ToString()%>'
   href='Readmore.aspx?oid=........'
   ....>
   ...</a>
```

and with that, the `<a>` tags will have IDs like `ID_32131, ID_4532455, ID_1231455` and the IDs will be unique as long as the database query returns unique articles.

Comment: <%# Eval("articleID").ToString()%> is not returning ant value

Comment: Have you checked the database query? Does it return such column?

Comment: yaa it is retuning value but some extra value i am reteriving title expected value should be "xyz" but real value is %20xyz